# How would I decode a hex value to ASCII in c++

Tags: c++, string, hex, decode

This is not a duplicate question because the other one is asking how to convert hex to a string, not decode it.

I want to convert a hex value to an an ASCII character. I want to do the exact same thing you can do in this website: http://string-functions.com/hex-string.aspx
If you put in 0000005B  it will output [

My code here will return a hex value. Assuming it returns 0000005B, I want to read [ as an LPCWSTR.

```
char mod_tostring(int state, int index, int size) {
int stringAddress = lua_tolstring(state, index, 0);
const char* const Base = (const char* const)stringAddress;
return Base[0]; };
```

Base[0] is the hex value. As an example, Base[0] might be 0000005B.

Comment: I don't understand the difference between the two questions. In both, it seems that you have something string-like (`Base`, which is of type `const char*`) containing the *characters* `0000005B` (or whatever), and you are trying to determine the ASCII character (as a `char`) corresponding to the hex number in the string.

Comment: The other one was a wrong question. It's how to literally display 0000005B  in string form, not decode it to a character.

Comment: It seems that *one* answerer *mis*-interpreted it that way; clearly that was not your intent. Don't open a new question when a single user misinterprets your question; just clarify the original question!

Comment: It would be confusing for users in the future to see the answers with an edited question. Imagine if asked how many turtles are there and then I changed the question to ask how many turtles are in North America. The people viewing the question in the future would see answers for how many turtles there are and ones about in North America.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am giving you program to convert hexadecimal to ASCII char value. You can tailor it according to your needs.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
char conv(char *s)
{
    int l=strlen(s),i,v=0,ans=0,p;
    for(i=l-1;i>=0;i--)
    {
        if(s[i]>='A')
            p=s[i]-'A'+10;
        else
            p=s[i]-48;
        ans+=p*pow(16,v++);         
    }
    return (char)ans;
}
int main()
{
    printf("%c",conv("0000005B"));
}
```

Comment: I'm not using cout. swprintf isn't working for me.
`wchar_t szBuff[64];
     char Error = mod_tostring(lua_State, -1, 140);
     swprintf(szBuff, L"Error: %p", Error);
     printConsole(hwnd, OutputBoxHWND, szBuff);` It's just printing 0000005B

Comment: I can't get you.However syntax for swprintf is int _swprintf_l(     wchar_t *buffer,     size_t count,  
   const wchar_t *format,    locale_t locale [,     argument] ...   );   you have missed size_t count.

Comment: It works when I do swprintf that way. If I do it to the char, it just prints 0000005B. Would you like me to provide a screenshot?

Comment: Get the output from mod_to_string() function and pass that as input to the conv() function which I is there above or Clearly say me what you want to print.

Comment: As a test I tried to do conv("0000005B") and it's still giving me 0000005B

Comment: http://ideone.com/DTuoBe   Check this link it is giving correct answer.

Comment: That way it would work out for me. I'm using swprintf. It prints 0000005B with that. I don't know how to make it work with swprintf! I know your code works.

Comment: http://ideone.com/DTuoBe Now check this it is working with swprintf.

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you!!!!!! It's working now.

Comment: I actually need just a bit more help. mod_totring is returning a char, not a char*. I don't know how to convert that.

Comment: This is growing ask it as a separate question.

Comment: Thanks, I got it on my own.